# Global fixtures pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Why all fixtures in pytest are global?
For example:

```
tests/
    conftest.py
        # content of tests/conftest.py
        import pytest

        @pytest.fixture
        def fixture_1():
            pass

    test_something.py
        # content of tests/test_something.py
        def test_something(fixture_2):
            assert fixture_2 != None

    subfolder/
        conftest.py
            # content of tests/subfolder/conftest.py
            import pytest

            @pytest.fixture
            def fixture_2(username):
                pass
```

As you can see I can get fixture_2 from second level in test from first level folder.
 Is any possibility to set fixture just for one package?